# Native Instruments Traktor Kontrol Z1

Tags: drivers, sound

Sadly, as directed by Native Instruments support, there are no current ALSA drivers available for the Traktor Kontrol Z1.

http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix:Vendor-Native_Instruments

The support team said I just need to wait until someone writes a Linux driver for it.

1. Is there any way to sponsor someone to write drivers?
2. I'm a web developer (mostly PHP). How big a leap is it to look into writing a driver? Any recommendations on resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing drivers is a whole different ball game.

Even though they do not support it NI does have some well working cards. Good to see :)

[From their help](http://www.native-instruments.com/en/support/online-help/compatibility/linux/):

> Some NI audio interfaces can also be used under Linux operating systems. This includes AUDIO 4 DJ/AUDIO 8 DJ, AUDIO KONTROL 1, GUITAR RIG MOBILE I/O, the KORE 1 controller, the second and third generations of the RIG KONTROL, and the SESSION I/O interface. Both the audio and MIDI functions of these devices are supported.
>
> **The necessary ALSA drivers are included in kernel versions 2.6.22 and above**. Native Instruments does not provide any kind of support or guarantee for these drivers or for using its products under Linux.
>
> For more information on ALSA drivers, please see [here](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Main_Page).
>
> All Native Instruments ALSA drivers are listed [here](http://alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix:Vendor-Native_Instruments).

There is no Z1 amongst it and there are drivers for ALSA so you could track down someone who is in charge of these and ask if they are willing to help with a Z1. But that might be seen as inappropriate.

The part in bold sounds promising though; sometimes you can use another cards setup (as in the previous version) to get a newer one working since internally lots of cards are identical.

How about start debugging the information as asked [here](http://alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Help_To_Debug). This will gather all the information needed to get it supported. Maybe it is fairly easy to get working based on the current working cards.

Besides that I would start a conversation on the [ALSA mailing lists](http://alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Mailing-lists) to get this card on their radar. Sometimes all it needs is a little attention to get things rolling.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'll investigate the possibility of trying other card drivers. Certainly I previously had the Komplete Audio 6 and it worked fine in Linux. I'll check out the debugging and regarding the mailing lists - perhaps you could advise whether I should subscribe to alsa-devel or alsa-user?

Comment: Mailing list: see the last link. It has "subscribe for..." per section.